# How to work with foreign key with mutiple selection

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

*Hi Everyone i am trying to achieve select multiple car with foreign key relation because  we need to store data with mutiple row, i am tried with manytomany fied but this is not effective as per our requirement, thats way i am trying solve this with foreign key, pls help me out.*

**models.py**

```
class Car_team(BaseModel):
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Team',
        null=True,
    )
    car=models.ForeignKey(
        Car, 
        models.CASCADE, 
        verbose_name='Car', 
        null=True)
    city =models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='City',
    )
    start_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CarTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):         
    start_date=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today, label='Start Date')
    car = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Car.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = Car_team
        fields = ['car','team','city','start_date']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(CarTeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_date'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        widgets = {
            'car': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def add_carteam(request, city_id=None, id=None):

    if id is not None:
        carteam = get_object_or_404(Car_team, city_id=city_id, pk=id)
    else:
        carteam = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CarTeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=carteam)
        if form.is_valid():
            car = form.cleaned_data['car']
            team = form.cleaned_data['team']
            start_date = Car_team.objects.filter(car__in=car).values_list('start_date', flat=True).filter(end_date__isnull=True)
            # if start_date:
            #     messages.error(request,'Car already assigned to another team!')
            query = Car_team.objects.filter(car__in=car).exists()
            query_set = Car_team.objects.filter(car__in=car).values_list('team', flat=True)
            team_name = Team.objects.filter(pk__in=query_set).values_list('name', flat=True)
            car_id = Car_team.objects.filter(car__in=car).values_list('car', flat=True) 
            car_number=Car.objects.filter(pk__in=car_id).values_list('car_number', flat=True)
            if query_set and start_date:
                messages.error(request,'Car already assigned to team {} {}!'.format(team_name,car_number))
            # if query:
            #     messages.error(request,'Car already assigned to another team!')
            else:
                #print(start_query)
                form.save()
                messages.success(request,'Assign Cars To Teams data added successfully!')
                return redirect('/fleet/carteam_list')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please correct the error below.',form.errors)
    else:
        form = CarTeamForm(instance=carteam)
    context = {
        'menu_car_management': 'active',
        'submenu_carteam': 'active',
        'form': form,
        'id': id,
        'city_id': city_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'hiringprocess/addcarteam_form.html', context=context)
```

**addcarteam_form.html**

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fleet/addcarteam/{{city_id}}/add" autocomplete="off">
            {% csrf_token %}
           
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-widget"> 
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form.team|as_crispy_field}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form.city|as_crispy_field}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form.start_date|as_crispy_field}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 scroll">
                                {% for i in form.car %}
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        {{i}}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>

                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
                <span id="btn_txt">Save</span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Output Error**

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /fleet/addcarteam/1/add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\20_jan_2022_everest\everest_jarvis\fleet\views.py", line 3879, in add_carteam
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 185, in is_valid     
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors       
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 383, in full_clean   
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 398, in _post_clean 
    self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 60, in construct_instance
    f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 853, in save_form_data
    setattr(instance, self.name, data)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 211, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Car: HR38AB6029>, <Car: HR38AB6822>]>": "Car_team.car" must be a "Car" instance.        
ERROR "POST /fleet/addcarteam/1/add HTTP/1.1" 500 114584
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding `ForeignKey`. `CarTeam.car` can represent one and only one car, and therefore the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget is inappropriate. Use the default, or maybe `RadioSelect`.

If you are expecting it to represent multiple cars, it is either ManyToMany, or you have it back to front, and you should have a `car_team` ForeignKey on the `Car` model. The set of cars related to a `car_team` instance is available through that instance as the specified related_name, which defaults to `car_set`.

You'll need a differerent form to select multiple cars (free ones: queryset `Car.objects.filter( car_team__isnull=True )` and then for each, set its `car_team` to the one you are operating on, and save it.

You can process multiple forms in one view. Use form prefix if any of the field names will clash.